# How Silverlight 4 to consume restful service from Alfresco Webscript?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, alfresco

I am working on a project which request to get/send data from Alfresco.

Alfresco can provide webscript as restful service.

So how Silverlight 4 to consume restful service from Alfresco Webscript?

Alfresco also provide WebService. How SL 4 can use those Web Services?

Answer (score 1):

Most Alfresco webscripts are RESTful, and return JSON.

If you have a look through http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index then it'll let you see what webscripts there are, what parameters they take, and some information on what they return.

Then, when you've found your webscript, you likely want to fetch it with the appropriate parameters specified, and potentially with appropriate authentication. If it's a JSON returning webscript, you then parse the JSON with a suitable parser for your language, and then work with the data you got back.

You might also want to read through http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts to get a better idea of how webscripts work.